# Titanium module build failed while integrating 3rd party framework

Tags: iphone, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I am trying to integrate 3rd party framework "LTU" for image processing. The thing how this SDK is integrated into the module is a bit different from my past experiences. The SDK needs to copy whole xcode project (which is the framework itself) into the module.

Now when I try to build the module it throws error stating that the framework not exist on the path. See the full error log:

```
invindmac6s-iMac:iphone paresh.thakor$ clear

invindmac6s-iMac:iphone paresh.thakor$ ./build.py
[WARN] please update the manifest key: 'copyright' to a non-default value
[WARN] please update the manifest key: 'license' to a non-default value
[WARN] please update the manifest key: 'copyright' to a non-default value
[WARN] please update the LICENSE file with your license text before distributing
Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos8.1

2015-03-30 17:58:18.581 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6611/IDEFoundation/SourceControl/Model/IDESourceControlManager.m:423
Details:  Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain Code=-1 "Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion" UserInfo=0x7ff08954d6e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion}
Object:   <IDESourceControlManager: 0x7ff08bcfb6e0>
Method:   -loadRepositories
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff089403f50>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.643 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/F0A63082-8D50-417C-805B-1B84F9CF63EA.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.644 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/33D52D5C-E146-4A0F-BEB2-AC4A6CDC2BBA.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.644 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/BCCEC865-598B-4C92-A37B-2CCB12A7220E.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.644 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/8C23F2B2-CD26-4FA6-8932-AC95A6F5431A.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.645 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/432B5641-C681-432F-9797-632210CA0D03.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.645 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/2FCDDE5D-E9DA-4F89-8484-863761130107.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.645 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/84ED421F-771F-42B5-BF82-B2264B4ACCF6.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.645 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/9839AC5F-F5F8-4FDD-B692-87DACFEECA11.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.646 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/27407B36-9F1A-421F-8E82-DE481A50AA4B.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
2015-03-30 17:58:18.646 xcodebuild[61617:1682350] [MT] IDELogStore: Log record's backing file ("/Users/paresh.thakor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LTUiOS-hgdzwjjxjorkmwatuqekdkbjheyl/Logs/Build/4848BA39-10CD-4DD5-94EB-473EB1A1137E.xcactivitylog") is missing. Skipping.
=== BUILD TARGET LTUiOS OF PROJECT LTUiOS WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies

Libtool build/LTUiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/LTUiOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libComInvestisLtu.a normal armv7
    cd /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/build/Release-iphoneos -L/Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/LTUSDK/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/build/LTUiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/LTUiOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ComInvestisLtu.LinkFileList /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/LTUSDK/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libLTUSDK-lib.a -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreImage -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework Foundation -o /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/build/LTUiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/LTUiOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libComInvestisLtu.a
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/LTUSDK/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libLTUSDK-lib.a (No such file or directory)

Libtool build/LTUiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/LTUiOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libComInvestisLtu.a normal arm64
    cd /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only arm64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/build/Release-iphoneos -L/Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/LTUSDK/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/build/LTUiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/LTUiOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ComInvestisLtu.LinkFileList /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/LTUSDK/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libLTUSDK-lib.a -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreImage -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework Foundation -o /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/build/LTUiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/LTUiOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libComInvestisLtu.a
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Source/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/LTUiOS/iphone/LTUSDK/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libLTUSDK-lib.a (No such file or directory)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Libtool build/LTUiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/LTUiOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libComInvestisLtu.a normal armv7
    Libtool build/LTUiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/LTUiOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libComInvestisLtu.a normal arm64
(2 failures)
xcodebuild failed
invindmac6s-iMac:iphone paresh.thakor$
```

The framework which is built goes into the products folder after build but the compiler tries to find it on the path mentioned in error.

Check my directory structure as attached here.
[image]

**Module.xcconfig:**

```
//
// PLACE ANY BUILD DEFINITIONS IN THIS FILE AND THEY WILL BE 
// PICKED UP DURING THE APP BUILD FOR YOUR MODULE
//
// see the following webpage for instructions on the settings
// for this file:
// http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/400-Build_Configurations/build_configs.html
// 

//
// How to add a Framework (example)
//
// OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework Foo
//
// Adding a framework for a specific version(s) of iPhone:
//
// OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos4*]=$(inherited) -framework Foo
// OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphonesimulator4*]=$(inherited) -framework Foo
//
OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework libLTUSDK-lib.a -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreImage -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework Foundation
//
// How to add a compiler define:
//
// OTHER_CFLAGS=$(inherited) -DFOO=1
//
//
// IMPORTANT NOTE: always use $(inherited) in your overrides
//
```

Correct me if anything is wrong here.

Comment: Did you add the framework to the module's platform directory? What is your _module.xcconfig_ file ?

Comment: Check this out https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-14555?focusedCommentId=283914&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-283914

Comment: @EduardoGomez: How can I add the framework to module's platform directory? As you can see I have integrated the whole xcode project inside module and the framework will be built only when required. I am not making the framework first and adding. I need to add the framework which is built when the whole module is going to be built.

Comment: The link I've sent over clearly specifies how _FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS_ allow the application to find the framework. Sorry I'm not sure what you mean with "building the framework only when required".

Comment: @EduardoGomez: It means when I run build.py from terminal to make module, the required "libLTUSDK-lib.a" framework is generated. The framework is not generated before I run build.py to make module.

Comment: I quit the project as the problem was unsolved.

Comment: You giving up that easy? You may want to check this doc http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Project-section-43288810_iOSModuleProject-AddaThird-PartyFramework and double check to make sure you're correctly following the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response @EduardoGomez but the thing is not I have given up but it's that client put the project on hold, so, I don't need to work on that :). I will sure look into this just to explore new things :)